# making Y-axis in Google chart as the major axis

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to make a google chart where the major axis is the vertical axis. the example in this [link](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#line_chart) shows a line chart. the major axis here is the horizontal axis because all the lines' data are connected to this axis. in this [example](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#line_chart) how can I swap the axis in a way that will make the "letters" on the vertical axis and the numbers on the horizontal axis?. I could not find any information on how to do that. here is an overview on the [axis](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#Terminology).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by Sergey over on your [thread on the Google Visualization API discussion group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-visualization-api/m59Hy52Y3SI/ZbX2pIdUdkkJ), but to repeat here for those seeking an answer, you can set the "orientation" option to "vertical" to flip the chart's orientation.